# vagrant - memory and cpus definitions are not working

Tags: vagrant

I have the following vagrant configuration:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vagrant.plugins = "vagrant-docker-compose"
  config.vm.provision :docker
  config.vm.provision :docker_compose
  
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"


  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 10240
    v.cpus = 4
  end


  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y make
  SHELL
end
```

vagrant: 2.2.18

here is the output of `vagrant up --debug`: https://pastebin.com/SXZaS9Yp

The memory and the cpus parts are ignored.
Why?

Thanks

Comment: Probably because you're not running with Virtualbox?

Comment: @AKX using Virtualbox

Comment: What's with the docker stuff in the vagrantfile then?

Comment: @AKX Why should that have any effect on the VB memory and CPU.. its standart

Comment: works fine from my side (using vagrant 2.2.13 but not sure that's the issue), you can use the debug flag to check vm properties

Comment: @FredericHenri - here is the output: https://pastebin.com/SXZaS9Yp thanks

Comment: strange, I am running on macOS and this is running fine, try setting the property `v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "4"]` and `v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "10240"]`

Comment: @FredericHenri already did that... nothing

Comment: Did you even try to run as an administrator? Maybe this is the reason....

Comment: @JTejedor Just did... nothing. very odd )-: